# In bash, how to capture some output in variable, letting rest got to standard output

Tags: bash, output-redirect

I'm aware of the `bash` "capture output" capability, along the lines of (two separate files):

```
sub.sh:     echo hello
main.sh:    greeting="$(./sub.sh)"
```

This will set the `greeting` variable to be `hello`.

However, I need to write a script where I want to just capture *some* information, allowing the rest to got to "normal" standard output:

```
sub.sh:     xyzzy hello ; plugh goodbye
main.sh:    greeting="$(./sub.sh)"
```

What I would like is for `hello` to be placed in the `greeting` variable but `goodbye` to be sent to the standard output of `main.sh`.

What do the magic commands `xyzzy` and `plugh` need to be replaced with above (or what can I do in `main.sh`), in order to achieve this behaviour? I *suspect* it could be done with some sneaky fiddling around of handle-based redirections but I'm not sure. If not possible, I'll have to revert to writing one of the items to a temporary file to be picked up later, but I'd prefer not to do that.

---

To make things clearer, here's the test case I'm using (currently using the non-working file handle 3 method). First `sub.sh`:

```
echo xx_greeting >&3 # This should be captured to variable.
echo xx_stdout       # This should show up on stdout.
echo xx_stderr >&2   # This should show up on stderr.
```

Then `main.sh`:

```
greeting="$(./sub.sh)" 3>&1
echo "Greeting was ${greeting}"
```

And I run it thus:

```
./main.sh >/tmp/out 2>/tmp.err
```

expecting to see the following files:

```
/tmp/out:
    xx_stdout
    Greeting was xx_greeting 
/tmp/err:
    xx_stderr
```

Comment: Each file descriptor points to only one place when a program is exec'd, even if that place is the stdin of a separate program that performs fancy logic (like reading the first line then forwarding the rest somewhere else).

Comment: Use an extra fd: `sub.sh: echo hello; echo nasty >&3`, `main.sh: exec 3>&1; var=$(./sub.sh)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by introducing an *extra* file descriptor as follows. First the `sub.sh` script for testing, which simply writes a different thing to three different descriptors (implicit `>&1` for the first):

```
echo for-var
echo for-out >&3
echo for-err >&2
```

Second, the `main.sh` which calls it:

```
exec 3>&1
greeting="$(./sub.sh)"
echo "Variable is ${greeting}"
```

Then you simply run it ensuring you know what output is going to the different locations:

```
pax> ./main.sh > xxout 2> xxerr

pax> cat xxout
for-out
Variable is for-var

pax> cat xxerr
for-err
```

Hence you can see that, when calling `sub.sh` from `main.sh`, stuff written to file handle 1 goes to the capture variable, stuff written to file handle 2 goes to standard error, and stuff written to file handle 3 goes to standard output.